# Matrix of Vectors Of different lengths in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Is it possible to create a matrix of vectors in R?
Of any other type of support to put vectors of different lengths in 2D Table.
I would like to create an empty matrix where I could assign manually a vector to every element of the matrix. For example M[1,2]<-c(1,2,3) and
M[2,2]<-c(3,2,1).

When I try to this’ I have warnings that the affections do not respect the size of what it replaces.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You can have 3d arrays or list of lists of vectors.

Comment: Store them in a list instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a matrix of lists like below

```
M <- matrix(list(), 2, 2)
M[1, 2] <- list(c(1, 2, 3))
M[2, 2] <- list(c(3, 2, 1))
```